# Meshgrid with more than 3 vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following `m=7` vectors in Matlab

```
beta1grid=(1:1:3);
beta2grid=(0:0.5:1); 
deltagrid=(-4:1:-2);  
gamma1grid=(-2:1:0);
gamma2grid=(-2:0.5:-1);
alpha1grid=(1:1:3);
alpha2grid=(-2:1:0);
```

Each vector has `n=3` elements. 
I want to construct the matrix `A` of dimension `(n^m)x(m)`, i.e. `2187x7`, listing in each row a possible combination of elements from the vectors above.

Comment: The post that is linked as duplicate specifically asked for 4D, but I made it so that it generalized to N-dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `ndgrid`:

```
[b1, b2, d, g1, g2, a1, a2] = ndgrid(beta1grid, beta2grid, deltagrid, gamma1grid, gamma2grid, alpha1grid, alpha2grid);
A = horzcat(b1(:), b2(:), d(:), g1(:), g2(:), a1(:), a2(:));
```